# Get multi-dimensional array sizes given only generic type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

First, what I'm trying to accomplish- I find the C# interactive window available with Roslyn to be very useful. One of it's more interesting features is that it can take any `IEnumerable` and prints out its contents in a human readable form.

For example, typing:

> var a = new[,] { {3, 4}, {5, 6} }; a

Will print:

> int[2, 2] { { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } }

I'm trying to replicate this behavior in my own extension method on `IEnumerable` (for debugging purposes). Printing the elements themselves is easy, the trouble I'm running into is how to get the array dimensions given only an `IEnumerable<T>`.

This is what I have so far for getting the type's name and size:

```
private static String getFormattedTypeName<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{            
    var enumerableType = enumerable.GetType();

    var typeNameAndSize = new StringBuilder();
    typeNameAndSize.Append(enumerableType.Name.Split('`').First());

    var genericArguments = enumerableType.GetGenericArguments();
    if (genericArguments.Length != 0)
    {
        typeNameAndSize.Append(String.Format("<{0}> ({1})", 
            String.Join(",", genericArguments.Select(t => t.Name)),
            enumerable.Count()));
    }
    else if (enumerableType.IsArray)
    {
        //Can I get the length of each array dimension from the type???
    }

    return typeNameAndSize.ToString();
}
```

My question is what is the best way to get the dimensions of multi-dimensional arrays where my comment indicates? I don't see any methods on `Type` which fit the bill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you know you are working with an `Array` via your check of `IsArray`, you can cast the `enumerable` to an `Array` and get the array bounds as follows:

```
private static Int32[] GetArrayBounds(Array value)
{
    var bounds = new Int32[value.Rank];
    for (var i = 0; i < value.Rank; i++)
        bounds[i] = value.GetLength(i);

    return bounds;
}
```

Where `Rank` tells you the number of dimensions in the array, and then subsequent calls to `GetLength` for a given dimension will tell you the size of that particular dimension.

Comment: @Romoku I specifically didn't ask about jagged arrays, as there is no way to give a single size to the interior arrays.