# In C#, how can I create a value type variable at runtime?

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I am attempting to implement a method like:

```
(Func<T> getFn, Action<T> setFn) MakePair<T>(T initialVal) {
}
```

It will return two runtime generated lambdas that get and set a dynamically created variable using `Expression` trees to create the code.

My current solution is to dynamically create an array of the type with one element, and reference that:

```
(Func<T> getFn, Action<T> setFn) MakePair<T>(T initialVal) {
    var dynvar = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(T), 1);
    Expression<Func<Array>> f = () => dynvar;
    var dynref = Expression.Convert(f.Body, typeof(T).MakeArrayType());
    var e0 = Expression.Constant(0);
    var getBody = Expression.ArrayIndex(dynref, e0);
    var setParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var setBody = Expression.Assign(Expression.ArrayAccess(dynref, e0), setParam);
    
    var getFn = Expression.Lambda<Func<T>>(getBody).Compile();
    var setFn = Expression.Lambda<Action<T>>(setBody, setParam).Compile();

    return (getFn, setFn);
}
```

Is there a better way to create what may be a value type variable at runtime that can be read/written to than using an array?

Is there a better way to reference the runtime created array other than using a lambda to create the (field?) reference for use in the `ArrayIndex`/`ArrayAccess` method calls?

**Excessive Background Info**
For those that wonder, ultimately this came up in an attempt to create something like Perl auto-virification of lvalues for Perl hashes.

Imagine you have a `List<T>` with duplicate elements and want to create a `Dictionary<T,int>` that allows you to look up the count for each unique `T` in the list. You can use a few lines of code to count (in this case `T` is `int`):

```
var countDict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
foreach (var n in testarray) {
    countDict.TryGetValue(n, out int c);
    countDict[n] = c + 1;
}
```

But I want to do this with LINQ, and I want to avoid double-indexing `countDict` (interestingly, `ConcurrentDictionary` has `AddOrUpdate` for this purpose) so I use Aggregate:

```
var countDict = testarray.Aggregate(new Dictionary<int,int>(), (d, n) => { ++d[n]; return d; });
```

But this has a couple of issues. First, `Dictionary` won't create a value for a missing value, so you need a new type of `Dictionary` that auto-creates missing values using e.g. a seed lambda:

```
var countDict = testarray.Aggregate(new SeedDictionary<int, Ref<int>>(() => Ref.Of(() => 0)), (d, n) => { var r = d[n]; ++r.Value; return d; });
```

But you still have the lvalue problem, so you replace the plain `int` counter with a `Ref` class. Unfortunately, C# can't create a C++ first class `Ref` class, but using one based around auto-creating a setter lambda from a getter lambda (using expression trees) is close enough. (Unfortunately C# still won't accept `++d[n].Value;` even though it should be valid, so you have to create a temporary.)

But now you have the problem of creating multiple runtime integer variables to hold the counts. I extended the `Ref<>` class to take a lambda that returns a constant (`ConstantExpression`) and create a runtime variable and build a getter and setter with the constant being the initial value.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use Expression trees? Simple lambdas could also capture a local variable. But i don't see where this might be usefull.

Comment: what is the end goal of that function?

Comment: @DanielA.White I added some background explanation.

Comment: @Pretasoc I added some background explanation.

Comment: "Dictionary won't create a value for a missing value, so you need a new type of Dictionary that auto-creates missing values" why not check `.ContainsKey` and give an initial count 0?

Comment: *"Imagine you have a `List<T>` with duplicate elements and want to create a `Dictionary<T,int>` that allows you to look up the count for each unique T in the list.* OK, I am imagining it, and my imagination is `mylist.GroupBy(x=>x).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count())` and we're done. I don't understand why you are doing any of this stuff with expression trees and whatnot. Can you explain?

Comment: There are many ways to do what you ask with compiled expressions or delegates, all requiring creating instance of some reference type, but I don't see any benefits doing that instead of having simple `class Ref<T> { public T Value; }` and use simply `new Ref<int>()` for creating "multiple runtime variables"

Comment: @EricLippert So you are calling `GroupBy` which will create a `Lookup` internally, then you are breaking down the `Lookup` to create a `Dictionary`. I would do `var lu = mylist.ToLookup(x=>x)` and just use `lu[n].Count()` (or maybe `((ICollection<int>)lu[n]).Count`) which at least doesn't create two dictionary like objects. However, counting isn't the only reason to want a reference to a value type.

Comment: @IvanStoev Perhaps that should be called `OnHeap<T> where T : struct` instead? The `Ref` class is a more generic construct and I would prefer to have one class rather than a specialized type for this, but perhaps that isn't best.

Comment: @NetMage Well, you can call it whatever you like (`Variable<T>`? :-) All it needs to be is a mutable class with public gettable/settable field/property. Unfortunately cannot use standard `Tuple<T>` class because `Item1` has no setter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with some of the question commenters that expression trees seem unnecessary, so here is a simple implementation of the shown API without them:

```cs
struct Box<T> {
    public T Value;
}

(Func<T> getFn, Action<T> setFn) MakePair<T>(T initialVal) {
    var box = new Box<T> { Value = initialVal };
    return (() => box.Value, v => box.Value = v);
}
```

As an answer to the stated question (how to define `dynref` without a lambda), then, is there something wrong with the following modifications to `dynvar` and `dynref`?

```cs
var dynvar = new T[] { initialVal };
var dynref = Expression.Constant(dynvar);
```

Comment: While this doesn't answer the question (the `Ref` class can be used to capture an already existing lvalue (variable or array member) as well as create a dynamic one from a constant), perhaps this can be used to simplify the implementation of the constant case.

Comment: The `Expression` trees are used because the `Ref` class is generic, but if this can be used to simplify the constant case, then it does answer the question.

Comment: I changed my mind - it doesn't matter why I am using `Expression` trees, the question remains how to dynamically create an object (variable) using `Expression` trees without using `Array`.

Comment: I don't think is a complete answer to my final question, but it ended up serving my purposes close enough.